# APNS Payload Structure Design

Tags: php, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The APNS payload structure going to send through APNS's SSL channel in PHP is generated like this:

```
$payment = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $device_token) . pack('n', strlen($data)) . $data;
```

where:

- `$device_token` is 64-character Device Token generated & responded by APNS
- `$data` is an json-encoded array containing the parameters of APNS contents (e.g. message)

What is the reason behind such structure design?

The function [chr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) returns a one-character string containing the character specified by ascii. But `chr(0)` does not return a visible character, proven by:

```
echo '['.chr(0).']'; // which prints []
```

Next, the consecutive 3 [pack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) functions:

1. First one `pack('n', 32)` returns an empty space
2. Second one `pack('H*', $device_token)` returns a hexadecimal binary representation of the device token
3. Third one `pack('n', strlen($data))` returns an invisible character, proven by:

```
$data = array(
  'message' => '12345678',
);
$data = json_encode($data);
echo '[' .pack('n', strlen($data)) . ']'; // which returns []
```

and the last one is the json-encoded content.

Why does Apple design this structure? What's those invisible character for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `chr(0)` returns a byte that contains 0. It identifies the binary format you are using. `0` is used for the simple format, `1` is used for the enhanced format (which includes message identifier and expiration time) and `2` is used for the newer format they introduced in iOS7.

`pack('n', 32)` returns the number 32 encoded in two bytes. It represents the size in bytes of the device token. In this case I'm not sure why they need two bytes, since `32` can be stored in a single byte (and the size of the device token is always 32, so perhaps this field is not really necessary).

`pack('H*', $device_token)` packs the hex representation of the device token to a 32 byte binary representation. That's more efficient then sending the 64-byte hex representation.

`Third one pack('n', strlen($data))` return the length of the payload encoded in two bytes. Since the length of the payload is usually < 256 (256 is the limit), the first of those two bytes will usually contain `0`.

Those `invisible characters` are not characters at all. They are numbers that describe the notification.

You can read more about the simple binary format [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/LegacyFormat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH105-SW1).